# Get current page number of InDesign multi page document

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am trying to get the current page number of an InDesign page into a label. 
This is what I am using:

```
myLabel = myDocument.properties.name.replace(/\D+/,'').split(' ')[0].split('_')[0] + '_'
    + app.activeWindow.activePage.name +'_'+myCounter;
```

The issue I am running into is that I am running this from a multi page document, and instead of using the current page number, its using the first page number of the document in all labels in each page.

Here is the code that I think I am having issues with:

```
function myAddLabel(myDocument, myGraphic, myCounter, myLabelType, myLabelHeight, myLabelOffset, myStyle, mySwatch, myStoriesArray){ 
    var myLabel;
    var myLink = myGraphic.itemLink;
    var myPasteFromClipboard = false;
    //Create the label layer if it does not already exist. 
    var myLabelLayer = myDocument.layers.item("Coded Layout"); 
    try{ 
        myLabelLayer.name; 
    } 
    catch (myError){ 
        myLabelLayer = myDocument.layers.add({name:"Coded Layout"}); 
    } 
    //Label type defines the text that goes in the label.
    switch(myLabelType){
    //File name
        case 0:
            myLabel = myDocument.properties.name.replace(/\D+/,'').split(' ')[0].split('_')[0]+'_' + app.activeWindow.activePage.name+'_'+padNumber(myCounter);
            break;
```

Now I believe that the actual issue is with in this part of the script, if i select all the items on a page and run the script it works the way i want it to work.

```
function myAddLabels(myLabelType, myLabelHeight, myLabelOffset, myStyle, mySwatch){ 
var myDocument = app.documents.item(0);
myStoriesArray = new Array();

if (app.selection.length == 0) // If nothing is selected apply caption to all graphics in the document
    {
        var myConfirmation = confirm("Add captions to all images in the document?", false, "LabelGraphics.jsx" );
        if (myConfirmation == true)
            {
                var myGraphics = myDocument.allGraphics;
                }
        }
    else    
        { // If graphics are selected, just add captions to the selected items, as long as they are rectangles(image frames)
        var myConfirmation = true;
        var mySelections = app.selection;
        myGraphics = new Array();

        for(i = 0; i < mySelections.length; i++){
                if(mySelections[i] == "[object Rectangle]"){   //Check to make sure selection only includes rectangles
                        myGraphics.push(mySelections[i].allGraphics[0]);
                        }   
                    else{
                        //alert("Objects other than graphics were selected!");
                        //Nothing happens if you don't select at least one graphic
                        } 
                } 
            }
```

And what i need to do at this point is create a loop as you suggested to run though all pages from the first to last applying the label.

Comment: Can you add an example of your document name? That way the purpose of all those splits may become more clear. Note that the *very first* operation (replacing all that is not a digit with nothing) appears to make those very same splits unnecessary. It is also not clear *when* you are running this script. As it is, it should not set more than a single label.

Comment: Hi Jongware i have scrolling through your site all morning but can not find the answer, thanks for the reply. an example of the file name is ABCD1934 P2_1.indd. what i am trying to end up with a label which only contains the numbers in the file name, the page number and a count. e.g. 1934_2_001 thank you let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I am just trying to get something to work, i have edited an existing script. I think perhaps the script loops over all the graphics in the document then added a label to it, the label is what i sent earlier, am i correct in thinking i should try and get the script to just do a page at a time?

Comment: I have narrowed this down I believe to this section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `app.activeWindow.activePage.name` only returns the "name" (which indeed is the current page number) for the one page that is *visible* in your current (active) InDesign window. Unless your code actively switches the layout window to show each page in turn, it will always return the same number (and if the page currently shown is the first page, then you'd get exactly what you described).

To assign `myLabel` to each page number in an entire document, you need to loop over each of the document's *pages*:

```
for (p=0; p<myDocument.pages.length; p++)
{
     myLabel = myDocument.name.replace(/\D+/,'') + '_'
        + app.activeDocument.pages[p].name +'_'+myCounter;
     /* .. use myLabel here .. */
}
```

I removed the `split` commands because the regex already removes all of the characters that are not digits, and so there are no spaces or underscores left to split *on*.

Comment: Hi thank you for getting back to me, I am very thankful. This is the first time I have tried anything like this so its really beyond me, but I have become obsessed, I can not actually figure out where to place it. I put it in where I think you suggested but now its adding in the page number as the last page number of the document of all the pages. can i send you what I have and you show me where you suggest? I actually pulled some code from another one of your scripts to piece what i have together.

Comment: You can [edit] your post and add the **relevant** part of your script. [Minimizing your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is good but you overdid it a bit, so I cannot tell what's wrong with it now.

Comment: I have tried to edit it, but i don't think its working...i am thinking its more to do with one of the functions… if(app.documents.length != 0){ if(app.documents.item(0).allGraphics.length != 0){ …so I thought and I may be way off the mark, But i was thinking of writing in a new function to Get a count of all pages in the document, then changing it so that it goes through allGraphics on each page in the order from first to last page... is that a better way to do this..How do i share the script with you

Comment: Sorry – I did not realize the **edit** link would point to my answer! You can use the 'edit' button on *your own post*.